# Signs conserved by positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis

let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be two positive, linear and bounded operators on $L_2(0,1)$. For a given function $w \in C(0,1)$ if we define

$y_1(x)=(P_1^{-1}w)(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad y_2(x)=(P_2^{-1}w)(x),$

I want to know if $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ have the same sign (positive/negative) at each $x \in [0,1]$.

For a simple class of positive operators I can prove it. For example, for any $z \in L_2(0,1)$ define

$(P_1 z)(x)=M_1(x)z(x) \quad \text{and} \quad (P_2 z)(x)=M_2(x)z(x)$, where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are strictly positive and continuous on $[0,1]$. Then we have that

$y_1(x)=(P_1^{-1}w)(x)=M_1^{-1}(x)w(x) \quad \text{ and } \quad y_2(x)=(P_2^{-1}w)(x)=M_2^{-1}(x)w(x).$ In this case, owing to the positivity of $M_1$ and $M_2$, it is easily seen that both $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ have the same sign at each $x \in [0,1]$. I want to see if we can show this for any positive linear and bounded operators.

Thanks.

Comment: By "positive operator" do you mean positive definite or positivity preserving?

Comment: Hi Robert, I mean positive definite.